# How to retrieve numbers from data using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, sorting, numbers

I am trying to retrieve the numbers after the letters and before the dollar signs. I have been receiving "null" as the output when I run my code.

For example: the numbers 2.1315, 1.94733, 1.07511 from VOO**2.1315**$262.67$86.88$559.88DIS**1.94733**$104.45$27.77$203.40IWM**1.07511**$122.55...

```
var data = "VOO2.1315$262.67$86.88$559.88DIS1.94733$104.45$27.77$203.40IWM1.07511$122.55$14.98$131.75DAL5$24.04-$44.26$120.19XOM2$42.46-$18.40$84.92VYM1$77.59$7.15$77.59SBUX1.19403$76.64$15.12$91.51"; 
var regex = /^\d+\.\d{0,2}$/g;
var found = data.match(regex);
console.log(found);
console.log(data);
```

Comment: You are using anchors to assert the start `^` and the end `$` of the string. Using the pattern `\d+\.\d{0,2}` will match 0-2 digits after the dot and will not fully match `2.1315` Do you only want to match decimal numbers after a char a-zA-Z?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made cast from string in number, if you do not need then delete `.map(Number)`

Lookbehind assertions it's available on the ECMA-262 specification

```
const data = 'VOO2.1315$262.67$86.88$559.88DIS1.94733$104.45$27.77$203.40IWM1.07511$122.55$14.98$131.75DAL5$24.04-$44.26$120.19XOM2$42.46-$18.40$84.92VYM1$77.59$7.15$77.59SBUX1.19403$76.64$15.12$91.51';
const regex = /(?<=[a-z])\d+\.\d+(?=\$)/gi;

const numbers = data
  .match(regex)
  .map(Number);

console.log(numbers);
```

Older browsers do not support lookbehind in JavaScript regular expression. You have to use two regex

```
const data = 'VOO2.1315$262.67$86.88$559.88DIS1.94733$104.45$27.77$203.40IWM1.07511$122.55$14.98$131.75DAL5$24.04-$44.26$120.19XOM2$42.46-$18.40$84.92VYM1$77.59$7.15$77.59SBUX1.19403$76.64$15.12$91.51';
const regex = /[a-z](\d+\.\d+)\$/gi;

const numbers = data
  .match(regex)
  .map(item => item.match(/\d+\.\d+/))
  //  or you can use slice instead of regex
  // .map(item => item.slice(1, -1))
  .map(Number);

console.log(numbers);
```

output:

```
Array(25) [ 2.1315, 1.94733, 1.07511 1.19403 ]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Basically look for a letter followed by some digits, followed by a decimal point, followed by some more digits. Then for each of these entries, get rid of the letter, which is in the first position.

```
found = data.match(/[a-zA-Z]\d+\.\d+/g).map(m => Number(m.substr(1)));
```

`found` is an array of the values you are looking for.

Get rid of the `Number()` cast if you just want the string values.